# An invalid floating point operation occurred. SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, floating-point-exceptions

I have weird problem with this code: if I run it like shown below I get error:

> **An invalid floating point operation occurred.**

But if I change parameter `@Longitude` to -98.508730 **(*notice only last digit changed*)** code works just fine.

The code is supposed to lists properties in `@MilesRadius` around some LatLng point.
@Latitude and @Longitude parameters are of the same type as longitude and latitude fields in table Address.

What can I do here? Thanks.

```
DECLARE @Latitude decimal (10,6);
DECLARE @Longitude decimal (10,6);
DECLARE @MilesRadius int;
SET @Latitude = 29.607654
SET @Longitude = -98.508731
SET @MilesRadius  = 5

SELECT     ADR.LineOne as address, 
           ADR.City as city,           
           ADR.Latitude as latitude,
           ADR.Longitude as longitude, 
           ((3959 * acos(cos(radians(@Latitude)) * cos(radians(ADR.Latitude)) * cos(radians(ADR.Longitude) - radians(@Longitude)) + sin(radians(@Latitude)) * sin(radians(ADR.Latitude))))) as distance
FROM       Shared.Address ADR
WHERE      ADR.Latitude IS NOT NULL AND 
           ADR.Longitude IS NOT NULL AND 
           (3959 * acos(cos(radians(@Latitude)) * cos(radians(ADR.Latitude)) * cos(radians(ADR.Longitude) - radians(@Longitude)) + sin(radians(@Latitude)) * sin(radians(ADR.Latitude)))) < @MilesRadius                       
ORDER BY distance
```

Comment: You are missing the part of your query where you declare the variables, please add that to your question

Comment: I did. Sorry forgot that. Parameters Latitude and Longitude are of the same type as latitude and longitude fields in Address table. Decimal(10,6)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only function you are using that returns a domain error is [`ACOS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178627.aspx) and that occurs when the input is not in the range `-1 to +1` so you can just fiddle this case (I'm assuming the intermediate expression is something like `1.000000000001` due to rounding errors)

```
SELECT     ADR.LineOne as address, 
           ADR.City as city,           
           ADR.Latitude as latitude,
           ADR.Longitude as longitude, 
           distance
FROM       Shared.Address ADR
CROSS APPLY (SELECT cos(radians(@Latitude)) * cos(radians(ADR.Latitude)) * cos(radians(ADR.Longitude) - radians(@Longitude)) + sin(radians(@Latitude)) * sin(radians(ADR.Latitude))) T(ACosInput)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT ((3959 * acos(CASE WHEN ABS(ACosInput) > 1 THEN SIGN(ACosInput)*1 ELSE ACosInput END)))) T2(distance)
WHERE      ADR.Latitude IS NOT NULL AND 
           ADR.Longitude IS NOT NULL AND 
           distance < @MilesRadius                       
ORDER BY distance
```